# YAJSW error with public static class

Tags: java, service, wrapper, java-service-wrapper

I have a java application I am trying to start using YAJSW. It is just a simple "Hello World" application and I follow the instructions here: http://yajsw.sourceforge.net/#mozTocId527639

I have done the following:

- exported my project from eclipse as a runnable JAR file.
- I ran genconfig  - no problems
- I editted wrapper.conf and added the location of the jar file
- ran runConsole.bat and I get this error:

  > java.lang.IllegalAccessException: class org.rzo.yajsw.app.WrapperJVMMain can not access a member of class xxxx with modifiers "public static"

The class it refers to is the main class, which must be public static.  I am stuck!  Anyone out there with advice?

Comment: Can you please upload your hello world code which runs as service i want to check it how it works... or you can answer my question about yajsw...Thanks

Comment: I have moved on from using this and found another solution.  Best of luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same problem, (running yajsw-stable-11.0 on Java 1.6.0_30-b12, Win XP Pro v 2002 SP3):

```
INFO|wrapper|Service socket-proxy|12-04-11 11:48:32|init 
INFO|wrapper|Service socket-proxy|12-04-11 11:48:32|ahessian jmx service bound to port 15002
INFO|wrapper|Service socket-proxy|12-04-11 11:48:32|set state IDLE->STARTING
INFO|wrapper|Service socket-proxy|12-04-11 11:48:32|Win service: before service init
INFO|wrapper|Service socket-proxy|12-04-11 11:48:32|starting Process
INFO|wrapper|Service socket-proxy|12-04-11 11:48:32|Controller State: UNKNOWN -> WAITING
INFO|wrapper|Service socket-proxy|12-04-11 11:48:32|+ ServiceMain callback
INFO|wrapper|Service socket-proxy|12-04-11 11:48:32|reporting status 0
INFO|wrapper|Service socket-proxy|12-04-11 11:48:32|reporting status 0
INFO|wrapper|Service socket-proxy|12-04-11 11:48:32|onstart
INFO|wrapper|Service socket-proxy|12-04-11 11:48:32|working dir C:\dev\workspaceTax\socket-proxy
INFO|wrapper|Service socket-proxy|12-04-11 11:48:32|create script: scripts/trayMessage.gv
INFO|wrapper|Service socket-proxy|12-04-11 11:48:33|found script scripts/trayMessage.gv
INFO|wrapper|Service socket-proxy|12-04-11 11:48:33|spawning wrapped process
INFO|wrapper|Service socket-proxy|12-04-11 11:48:33|started process with pid 3720
INFO|wrapper|Service socket-proxy|12-04-11 11:48:33|waiting for termination of process
INFO|wrapper|Service socket-proxy|12-04-11 11:48:33|set state STARTING->RUNNING
INFO|3720/0|Service socket-proxy|12-04-11 11:48:33|[INFO] DefaultFileReplicator - Using "C:\WINDOWS\TEMP\vfs_cache" as temporary files store.
INFO|3720/0|Service socket-proxy|12-04-11 11:48:33|java.lang.IllegalAccessException: Class org.rzo.yajsw.app.WrapperJVMMain can not access a member of class [...].socketproxy.Proxy with modifiers "public static"
INFO|wrapper|Service socket-proxy|12-04-11 11:48:33|Trigger found: Exception
INFO|3720/0|Service socket-proxy|12-04-11 11:48:33| at sun.reflect.Reflection.ensureMemberAccess(Unknown Source)
INFO|wrapper|Service socket-proxy|12-04-11 11:48:33|start script scripts/trayMessage.gv
INFO|3720/0|Service socket-proxy|12-04-11 11:48:33| at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
INFO|3720/0|Service socket-proxy|12-04-11 11:48:33| at org.rzo.yajsw.app.WrapperJVMMain.executeMain(WrapperJVMMain.java:53)
INFO|3720/0|Service socket-proxy|12-04-11 11:48:33| at org.rzo.yajsw.app.WrapperJVMMain.main(WrapperJVMMain.java:36)
INFO|wrapper|Service socket-proxy|12-04-11 11:48:33|end script scripts/trayMessage.gv
INFO|3720/0|Service socket-proxy|12-04-11 11:48:34|process terminated
INFO|3720/0|Service socket-proxy|12-04-11 11:48:34|Controller State: WAITING -> PROCESS_KILLED
INFO|wrapper|Service socket-proxy|12-04-11 11:48:34|restart process due to default exit code rule
```

In my case the class containing the static public main method was not declared public, so it was package-private which is the default.

```
class Proxy {
...
    public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException{
        ...
        }
}
```

Public methods of package private classes are not visible by classes belonging to a different package, so this was the problem in my case. See for example https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5260467/public-methods-in-package-private-classes.

```
public class Proxy {
...
    public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException{
        ...
        }
}
```

Declaring the class public as above solved the problem for me. Maybe you could post some more details about the whole problem and somebody will post a solution. 
Regards
-GF