# Reflection - Method::getGenericReturnType no generic - visbility

Tags: java, generics, reflection, javac, java-bridge-method

### Description

I have an odd issue in which [Method::getGenericReturnType()](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/15/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/reflect/Method.html#getGenericReturnType()) is not able to retrieve the generic type information.

Here is the minimized version:

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Method method = B.class.getMethods()[0]; // foo() method inherited from A
        System.out.println(method.getGenericReturnType());
    }

    static class A {
        public List<String> foo() { return null; }
    }

    public static class B extends A {}
}
```

Output is

```
java.util.List
```

without any generic type information. This seems odd to me.

However, changing `A`s visibility to `public` and it correctly gives

```
java.util.List<java.lang.String>
```

---

### Question

I do not know if this is a bug or actually expected behavior. If it is expected, what is the reasoning behind it?

I am using OpenJDK 15 from AdoptOpenJDK:

```
// javac
javac 15.0.1

// java
openjdk version "15.0.1" 2020-10-20
OpenJDK Runtime Environment AdoptOpenJDK (build 15.0.1+9)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM AdoptOpenJDK (build 15.0.1+9, mixed mode, sharing)
```

A friend could also reproduce it in:

- JDK Zulu 8
- AdoptOpenJDK 10, 11, 14

---

### Findings

I experimented a lot and figured out that the only visibility-combination between `A` and `B` that triggers this issue is when `B` is `public` and `A` is **not** `public`. Any other combination and it works as expected again. So only

- B `public`, A `protected`
- B `public`, A `package-visible`
- B `public`, A `private`

show weird behavior.

I tried moving the code around in different files, putting it into different packages, adding or removing `static` here and there and nothing changed.

I also checked the [source code](https://github.com/openjdk/jdk/blob/master/src/java.base/share/classes/java/lang/reflect/Method.java#L291) of the method, which is

```
public Type getGenericReturnType() {
  if (getGenericSignature() != null) {
    return getGenericInfo().getReturnType();
  } else { return getReturnType();}
}
```

where `getGenericSignature()` relies on a `String signature` that is set during construction of the `Method` instance. It appears that it is `null` for some reason in above situation.

---

### Update 1

I was just checking out the bytecode of the classes and found this in `B.class`:

```
  public Test$B();
    descriptor: ()V
    flags: (0x0001) ACC_PUBLIC
    Code:
      stack=1, locals=1, args_size=1
         0: aload_0
         1: invokespecial #1                  // Method Test$A."<init>":()V
         4: return
      LineNumberTable:
        line 16: 0

  public java.util.List foo();
    descriptor: ()Ljava/util/List;
    flags: (0x1041) ACC_PUBLIC, ACC_BRIDGE, ACC_SYNTHETIC
    Code:
      stack=1, locals=1, args_size=1
         0: aload_0
         1: invokespecial #7                  // Method Test$A.foo:()Ljava/util/List;
         4: areturn
      LineNumberTable:
        line 16: 0
```

To me this looks like `B`, for some reason, created another method `foo()` that simply forwards the method call to `A`s `foo()` and hence has no generic type information.

Moreover, when calling `B.getDeclaredMethods()` it actually returns a method, namely

```
public java.util.List Test$B.foo()
```

Even though this method is supposed to exclude inherited methods (from the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/15/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Class.html#getDeclaredMethods())):

> Returns an array containing Method objects reflecting all the declared methods of the class or interface represented by this Class object, including public, protected, default (package) access, and private methods, **but excluding inherited methods**.

Which would now make sense if `B` really created a wrapper-method.

However, why is it creating such a method? Is there maybe a JLS section that explains this behavior?

Comment: What happens when you use `B.class.getDeclaredMethods()`? `getMethods()` only picks up `public` members, maybe that has some impact. (Only an assumption)

Comment: @Lino Only yields one method, `foo`. `toGenericString()` on it gives `public java.util.List Test$B.foo()`. I am surprised by this, as this method is supposed to **exclude** inherited methods (from doc: _but excluding inherited methods._).

Comment: @Lino Weird, the bytecode for `B` appears to list an additional `foo()` method (without generics) that just wraps `A`s true `foo()` method (updated the question).

Comment: I wanted to mention the same, I've found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5260523/5515060) which mentions that something funky happens with subclasses, but doesn't go into more detail...

Comment: I think what happens is that the compiler generates a synthetic bridge method in `B` during type erasure of `A#foo` and that reflection is picking that up. That would explain the observations but I do not really know why visibility plays a role in that process. See https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/bridgeMethods.html

Comment: Still doesn't really answer the question *why* the bridge method is generated in the subclass. Because it doesn't override `foo()`... but I think you're on the right track

Comment: @Lino [here you go](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65618066/1059372)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Let's take it slow here. First of all, [here is why](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-6342411) a bridge method is generated to begin with. Even if you drop generics, there will still be a bridge method. That is, this code:

```
static class A {
    public String foo() { return null; }
}

public static class B extends A {}
```

will still generate a `foo` method with `ACC_PUBLIC, ACC_BRIDGE, ACC_SYNTHETIC`. You can read the bug description and understand why that is needed.

On the other hand if you make `A` `public`, such a method will *not* be generated, the reason should be obvious, considering the previous bug explanation (I hope). So the idea is that if you have a *non-public* class, `javac` will generate a bridge method for the scenario above.

---

Now, if you add generics into that mix of synthetic methods, things start to shed some light. For example, you have this:

```
interface WithGeneric<T> {
    public WithGeneric<T> self(T s);
}

public class Impl implements WithGeneric<String> {

    @Override
    public WithGeneric<String> self(String s) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

There will be a bridge method generated too in `Impl.class`, but its declaration is going to be the erasure of the interface. In other words there will be *two* methods in `Impl.class`:

```
public WithGeneric<String> self(String) {...}

public WithGeneric self(Object) {...}
```

---

If you glue these two things:

- in case of non-public classes a bridge method will be created (so that reflection would work)
- in case of generics an *erased* bridge method will be created (so that erased calls would work)

things will make (somehow) sense.

Comment: That makes totally sense, thanks. Especially for the bug link, very insightful. Do you know why `javac` does not add the type signature to the bridge if it can? In my situation, I think, it could. I get that there are situations in which it can not keep the signature (as you have shown) but `javac` seems to not bother for simpler cases as well. If I manually add the signature in the bytecode it works again and seems to be accepted by the JVM. So Im just wondering why `javac` doesnt try to give the information in "safe cases" but maybe Im overlooking something.

Comment: @Zabuzard I was thinking of exactly the same and you are right. I guess this is an edge case that `javac` devs did not find suitable handling. You could file a ticket and find out, may be this is indeed a bug.

Comment: I wonder whether this bugfix is still necessary with [JEP 181](https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/181) giving nest-based access control in Java 11.

Comment: It is. `Method.invoke` checks if you can access the owner of the method - and as the owner of the method is package-private, you can't. To prevent that, you get a synthetic bridge method whose owner is the public class.

Answer (score 3):

When you declare `A` public, `B.class.getMethods()[0]` is not referencing `B`; It is referencing `A.foo()`, where the method is declared and the type is obtained because of the existance of the `signature`.

[image]

---

Declaring `A` non-public forces `B.class.getMethods()[0]` reference `B.foo()`.

As there is no declaration of the inherited method, the type can't be obtained from the call to `getGenericReturnType` due to type erasure being applied to generics.

In compile time:

**`List<String> foo()` becomes
`List foo()`.**

And that's all the information `B` could give to you regarding the method's return type, since the signature in `B.foo()` was just removed.

[image]

---

**Both `A` and `B` hold the same return type for `foo()`** : **`java.util.List`** (*without parameter type*)

This is `A.foo()`'s declared return type. The same than `B.foo()`:

[image]

The difference is that `A` has a valid signature, so it will complete the result from the call to `getGenericReturnType()` by adding the parameter types.

In the case of `B`, it will only show what it knows: just the return type.

---

***I suffered strong headaches trying to solve the visibility puzzle. For a complete explanation of why this happens, look up at Eugene's answer. Seriously, you can learn a lot from this type of guy.***

Comment: While this makes somewhat sense, I do not get why `B.getDeclaredMethods()` returns `foo()` although its meant to **exclude** inherited methods. If I got you right, your answer basically says that `B` does not have its own `foo()` method, yet I can see one in the bytecode and `B.getDeclaredMethods()` returns one as well. Sounds inconsistent to me. Do you maybe have some JLS sections that clarify the rules in this situation?

Comment: it has a foo() method, and just like A, the return type for both is List (without type). The difference is A holds the signature because it declares the method and parameters, while B gets a null value signature. So the only information it gets from `B.foo()` is that returns a List. The last method post on your question will indeed say signature==null for `B.foo`, so you get the basic return type obtained from `getReturnType()`, which is simply List

Comment: But in the case of `A`, the signature won't be null, so the info you get is "complete", as it will call `getGenericInfo().getReturnType()` instead.

Comment: Why does `B` have a `foo()` method (a synthetic bridge method)? Or do you mean it *inherited* it from `A`? Then, why does `B.getDlecaredMethods()` return `foo()` although its not allowed to show any inherited methods? And why does it suddenly work if you increase the visibility of `A` but still stick to `B.getMethods()[0]`. The visibility should not change the information available to `B`, should it? After all, `Test` does have access to `A` as well.

Comment: I don't really get what you are trying to say. The thing is: A has a signature; B doesn't. A returns the return type (List) + the info from the signature.

Comment: B doesn't have a signature. So it returns what he knows: the return type. In both cases, the return type is List. Without parameter types.

Comment: `B` does not declare its own `foo()` method. It only inherits one from `A`. Hence, `getDeclaredMethods()` should **not** show any method, yet it shows `foo()`. And your explanation seems to miss the point why `B.getMethods()[0]` suddenly has type information if the visibility of `A` is changed (although everyone in the snippet has still access to `A`). I think what happens here is that the compiler generated a synthetic bridge method in `B` for `foo()` during type erasure and that reflection is picking that up. I do not really know why the visibility plays a role though.

Comment: B extends from A, so it must show foo() as a method from B. It is a declared method, just like as wait(), equals(), toString(), notify(), and so on. You can check it by looking at the result of `B.class.getMethods()`. --

Comment: `B.class.getDeclaredMethods()` explicitly excludes any inherited methods. It does **not** show `equals`, `wait`, ... It should not show `foo` unless there is a bug or the compiler actually put a sneaky `foo` clone into it. And looking at https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/bridgeMethods.html I think that is exactly what happens. I dont have the full rules for this process yet though.

Comment: You are totally right, my bad there regarding declared methods.

Comment: So the issue is now getting to know how foo() becomes a declared method on B, when it is inherited and shouldn't to. The visibility of A is making a strange logic in there, as the javadocs are somehow against what's happening when A is private.

Comment: *I think what happens here is that the compiler generated a synthetic bridge method in B for foo() during type erasure and that reflection is picking that up.* Now I got you, and this makes a lot of sense. Trying this on different versions of java could show what changed on the logic of reflection and why this behaviour doesn't match with the official docs...

Comment: @Zabuzard It's not only happening with A's visibility, but also B's. If `B` isn't public, it cant find any declaredMethod if `A` isnt public either. So B will show foo() as declared method if `A` is not public + `B` is public. headache.

Comment: @aran [here is a pill](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65618066/1059372)

Comment: @Zabuzard also, thanks for this question, it made me learn something new today. And sorry for not getting your point before, I was stubborn here until I got what you were trying to say here. Thanks!!